# Where do math grads, who don't code, land up in industry?

Tags: career-path, productivity

Do they go into investment banking? Consulting? Start their own bar and restaurants? Are there any statistics known about what percentage of industry jobs for people with math degrees require coding? About what types of jobs don't require coding?

math grads = math undergrads, masters, PhDs who don't write code and have no desire to join the data science craze.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59739/discussion-on-question-by-user74196-where-do-math-grads-who-dont-code-land-up).

Comment: Great question!!!!